# CORS issue in Firefox and IE (works fine in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, firefox, asp.net-web-api

I am hitting CORS related errors in Firefox and IE, but everything is working perfectly in Chrome.

The two calls from my client in question are

1. General call to Facebook which works in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in IE 11. I am making a call to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token_info?client_id=myclientid&access_token=usersaccesstoken to verify their token is still valid. In IE I receive the following error: XMLHttpRequest for  required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
2. The second call is to my server which has CORS enabled everywhere (code pasted below). The funny bit is this is all on localhost so should be the same server. The error I am receiving is "The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44300/api/auth/login. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

CORS related Web API code

```
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

**Update 1**

Well, it works when deployed to Azure, but not on localhost. Both of these issues are fully resolved when deployed. Very strange, and very bad as I need to be able to test this stuff locally. But at least it's kind of working... might add some clues to solve.

**Update 2**

Consistently working when deployed (even those the client and server on different domains) and failing on localhost. I haven't been able to narrow anything down on why it's failing locally. Cleared cache and deleted local files, issue still presents. Completely opened up my server to CORS, issue still presents. The only thing I can guess is how Azure handles cross-Azure requests thereby bypassing the CORS issue when deployed. I really need to get it working locally though to test.

Comment: are you making request from `http` on local?

Comment: @charlietfl https to https on localhost, client and server are on different ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Not Sure But might fix the issue.

1) Open nuget package manager console in your web api project.

2) type Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and install it

3) After successful install type Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi and install it.

4) Please check your web.config file for following entries. if they are there then pls remove/comment them.

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

5) Now come to your controller file and import the namespace.  using System.Web.Http.Cors;

6) Now at the controller level type [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] to allow all types of origins, headers and methods to be accepted by the controller.